# bash execute functions based on certain word in arguments

Tags: bash, zsh

i have the following bash script contains multiple functions

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

#checks if the arguments is directory and extract the domain name from it
if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    domain=$(echo "$1" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.[a-z]+')
    WORKING_DIR="$1"
else
    domain="$1"
    echo "it is domain name"
fi

example_fun1(){
    ping -c 4 $domain
}

example_fun2(){
    nslookup $domain
}

for x in "$@" ;do
    example_fun1 $x
    example_fun2 $x
done
```

and run as following

```
./script.sh ./pathtofolder/example.com/ ./pathtofolder/test.com/
```

Or

```
./script.sh example.com test.com
```

and working probably BUT i need to add more feature which is check if certain word based in arguments like `fun1` it will execute function example_fun1 only

desired execution

```
./script.sh fun1 ./pathtofolder/example.com/ ./pathtofolder/test.com/
```

OR

```
./script.sh fun1 example.com test.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a question or just want someone to write it for you?

Comment: _working probably_ : Well: In your script, `$1` is both used to set up the variable `domain`, and also as a parameter to your functions. Is this intentional? Further, you pass a parameter to your functions, but never use it. Would you claim that this is (probably) _working_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function=""
if [[ $( echo $1 | grep fun1 ) ]]
then
     function="example_fun1"
     shift
elif [[ $( echo $1 | grep fun2 ) ]]
then
     function="example_fun2"
     shift
fi

#checks if the arguments is directory and extract the domain name from it

example_fun1(){
    ping -c 4 $domain
}

example_fun2(){
    nslookup $domain
}

if [[ "$function" != "" ]]
then
        for input in "$@"; do
            if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
                domain=$(echo "$1" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.[a-z]+')
                WORKING_DIR="$1"
            else
                domain="$1"
                echo "it is domain name"
            fi
            "$function"
            shift
        done
else
        for input in "$@"; do
            if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
                domain=$(echo "$1" | grep -iEo '[[:alnum:]-]+\.[a-z]+')
                WORKING_DIR="$1"
            else
                domain="$1"
                echo "it is domain name"
            fi
             example_fun1
             example_fun2
             shift
        done
fi
```

This way you can pass `fun1` and execute **only**  `fun1`
Or if you don't pass any of these for example both of them will be executed

Comment: MAN this is exactly what i need, i was frustrating about loop and if statement inside it.
really thanks it helps alot

Answer (score 1):

Assign the first parameter to a variable, then use that when calling the function.

```
func="example_$1"
shift

for x in "$@"; do
    "$func" "$x"
done
```

And your functions need to use their parameters, not a variable that's set in the main script:

```
example_fun1(){
    ping -c 4 "$1"
}

example_fun2(){
    nslookup "$1"
}
```

Comment: hi @barmar i guess this will force me to edit the script every time i need to execute certain function which is frustrating and to call the function as argument

Comment: Why are you saying that? This handles it automatically.

Comment: As long as all the function names begin with `example_`

Comment: You use `./script.sh fun1 ...` or `./script.sh fun2 ...`

Comment: handles it automatically by executing as following ? `./script.sh fun1 test.com/ example.com/` or `./script.sh fun2 test.com/ example.com/` i tried it but dose not work

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: it works but loop for the first argument and execute it twice like ```./aaa.sh fun1 google.com ask.com``` it ping google twice not touching the other argument

Comment: Your functions are using `$domain` instead of the function argument.

Comment: ohhhhh my bad :) it fixed now .
yup i was using `$domain` instead of `"$x"` and worked well
i have replaced it 
THANK YOU

Comment: You should be using `$1`, not `$x`.

Comment: i was trying to execute this against dir path which is directory named with domain name but it fails with `ping: ./google.com: Name or service not known` i suppose that because i was check if the `$1` is dir using first if statement

Comment: You need to remove the `./` from `$1` in the function.

Comment: Or you can do it in the loop if you need the same thing for all functions.

Comment: Your original code only does it for the first argument to the script, so it failed for all other arguments as well.

Comment: i moved if statement inside loop and replaced $1 with $domain and works well except i must provide fun1 (function name) before any arguments or it will fail. 
i think this because only  "$func" "$x" is mention in loop .
i tried to put ` "$func" "$x" || example_fun1` but fails i will see if i get workaround 
anyway thanks